# Why can't grant privileges to a role?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I created a role and set privileges to tables, then created a user and grant the role to it by postgres user.

After the user login database, it can't select any tables at all.

```
CREATE ROLE readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;

CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD '123';
GRANT readonly TO user1;
```

When check table privileges, I can't see the new user is been granted there:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_privileges where grantee='user1';
(null)
```

Why the grant command doesn't work?

PS: This way works in development environment but doesn't work in production environment.

Comment: Yes, no privilege was granted to `user1`. Still, the user will be able to `SELECT`, because it inherits the privileges from `readonly`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If login with `user1`, why it can't `SELECT`?

Comment: Either the table is in a different schema, or you didn't run the statements in your question, or you ran the statements in a different database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe After 2 days, I can select by the new user. I think if there is something cache in the database environment so that didn't grant successfully.